# when you have a master/slave db, how do you force a query to go to master or slaves?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, connection-pooling

When you have a master/slave setup, how can you force a particular query (say a write) to go to the master, and/or a slave server?

Answer (score 1):

You need a special adapter for active record.I haven't tested it, but this one may work: https://github.com/sd/master_slave_adapter

In the [RailsLab Scaling series](http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/07/16/episode-17-scaling-your-database-part-1) (by Gregg Pollack) the [masochism plugin](https://github.com/mislav/masochism) has been recommended but it looks like it hasn't been updated in quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

To go to master you can do it in that way

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_proxy.with_master do
   #your code
end
```

I hope it helps